# MaskedTextBox Focus Method Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I am using the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&FocusElement=Comment) in one of my applications, and I am using the MaskedTextBox control. When I call the Focus method on the control, it doesn't work. The Focus method works fine on TextBox controls, but it seems that the MaskedTextBox doesn't inherit from TextBox. Does anyone know how to programmatically give focus to this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works. I had to do this to the DatePicker in silverlight. Derive a control from MaskedTextBox and provide the following overrides.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _textBox = (TextBox)base.GetTemplateChild("TextBox");
}

public new void Focus()
{
    if (_textBox == null)
        base.Focus();
    else
        _textBox.Focus();
}

private TextBox _textBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should submit the issues to the project site so it can be fixed in the toolkit and everyone can benefit.

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did post it in the comments section, but it is no longer there. I will add it as a project issue.